# Vagrant hostmanager doesn't keep machine "alive"

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vagrant-plugin

Whenever I have a machine configured with hostmanager installed like this

hosts file (\System32\drivers\etc)

```
## vagrant-hostmanager-start id: 382a2553-2617-4b47-972f-87f95eea4f24
192.168.56.100  my.domain.dev
192.168.56.100  domain.dev
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

It keeps reverting the host to, takes about 10 minutes or something like that.
It just keeps disabling the configuration while the virtual box machine is still running

```
## vagrant-hostmanager-start id: 382a2553-2617-4b47-972f-87f95eea4f24
# 192.168.56.100    my.domain.dev
# 192.168.56.100    domain.dev
## vagrant-hostmanager-end
```

is there a way to keep it active?

Vagrantfile configuration:

```
Vagrant.configure('2') do |config|
  ....
  config.hostmanager.enabled = true
  config.hostmanager.manage_host = true
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently it wasn't vagrant or vagrant-hostmanager that was editing my hosts file and disabling the entries.

Editing the permissions under `groups and users` solved the problem.
set `deny write` for the `System` will keep vagrant "alive"